# Lucence SOLR not highlighting special characters like dot, slash in search result

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

Like in titile, I got the result from solr and the special characters are not highlighting in searching word

```
<em>00</em>:<em>00.000Z</em>
```

solr parameter

```
&hl.simple.pre=<em>&hl.simple.post=</em>
```

Example query: all:* and get Hello/World as

```
<em>Hello</em> / <em>World</em>
```

field analyzer:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
      add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
      analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
-->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
<!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
-->
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: please post the query you made and the analyzer chain for the highlighted field

Comment: I add some more details

Comment: how about this query : all:Hello/World ?

Comment: The result is the same, slash(special solr character) is not highlightet

Answer (score 0):

`StandardTokenizer` will weed out characters like `/` , so perhaps what you're looking for here is actually `WhitespaceTokenizer` . Other than that, the colon `:` sign has special significane for the lucene query parser and for the edismax, so perhaps you want to try your luck with the simpler but more robust dismax query parser

Comment: When I set WhitespaceTokenizer for query, I can't use *, an asterisk character for search.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use an asterix ? Are you getting any error messages

Comment: No that point, this just doesn't work - I set query for search Simo* and there is no result, I'm in 100% sure there is value with Simons, Simon etc. Before I set tokenizer to WhitespaceTokenizer, this behaviour worked correctly